# checking probability logic in the birthday problem

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

There are $5$ employees in the office.  What is the probability of $2$ of them being born in the same month?

I follow this logic. Just tell me where I am mistaken.

The prior probability of one person being born in a random specific month is $\frac{1}{12}$.

For two people it must be that person1 AND person2 being born in the same month is $\frac{1}{12}\times\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{144}$.

For person1 and person3 it must still be $\frac{1}{144}$ and we must then calculate 'OR' $\frac{1}{144}+\frac{1}{144}$...

Hence there are 5 people out of which we choose 2. That is $\frac{5!}{(2!\times(5-2)!}=10$. Thus, the result must be $\frac{10}{144}$ which is $6.9\%$.

So where do I go wrong?

Comment: As for where you went wrong: You can only sum probabilites of events that are disjoint. Yours are not.

Comment: There are (at least) two errors here. First, $1/144$ is the probability that person 1 and person 2 are both born in June. It is also the probability that they are both born in March, and similarly for each of the other months. As these events are mutually exclusive, the probability that 1 and 2 are born in the same month is $12/144=1/12$. Second, the event that 1 and 2 are born in the same month, the event that 1 and 3 are born in the same month, etc., are not mutually exclusive, so it is not correct to simply add their probabilities.

Comment: Expanding on Florian's comment, if you want a solution that's more similar to what you tried, the appropriate tool to use is [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The basic idea is that when you do as you did, you count a sitution in which persons $1$, $2$ and $3$ are all born the same month multiple times (once for persons $1$ and $2$, another for persons $1$ and $3$, and one last time for persons $2$ and $3$). Inclusion-exclusion corrects this overcounting.

Comment: @AndreasBlass hits in on the nail, if you'd like to know one place you went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be the desired probability, and $q=1-p$. Then $q$ is the probability that each employee is born on a different month. How many possibilities are there for such an arrangement of birth months?

We can pick $5$ out of the $12$ months in $\binom{12}{5}$ ways, and then assign them to each employee in $5!$ ways, for a total of $\binom{12}{5}\cdot5!=\frac{12!}{7!}$ scenarios. On the other hand, the total number of scenarios is $12^5$, obtained by picking one month for each of the $5$ different employees. Hence:

$$q=\frac{\frac{12!}{7!}}{12^5}\simeq38.19\%$$

and the desired probability is $p=1-q\simeq61.81\%$.

Comment: this is a good solution but I just don't find the mistake in my reasoning

Comment: I have commented on the question.